# ¿Alguna idea de una expresión regular para recoger el contenido del campo "descripcion"?

Tags: javascript, array, json, regex, objeto

Tengo este texto, y me gustaría saber a través de una expresión regular como recoger únicamente el contenido que se encuentra en los campos con la etiqueta descripcion".

```
[{"keyword":"gato","url":"https://static.arasaac.org/pictograms/2406/2406_500.png","descripcion":" m. y f. Mamífero carnívoro doméstico de cabeza redonda, lengua muy áspera, patas cortas armadas de uñas fuertes, agudas y retráctiles, pelaje espeso y suave, de diversos colores, y ojos cuya pupila se dilata para ver en la oscuridad.","plural":"gatos"},{"keyword":"gato","url":"https://static.arasaac.org/pictograms/3333/3333_500.png","descripcion":"m. Instrumento de hierro que sirve para agarrar fuertemente la madera y llevarla a donde se pretende, y que se usa para echar aros a las cubas, y en el oficio de portaventanero.","plural":"gatos"},{"keyword":"gato","url":"https://static.arasaac.org/pictograms/7114/7114_500.png","descripcion":" m. y f. Mamífero carnívoro doméstico de cabeza redonda, lengua muy áspera, patas cortas armadas de uñas fuertes, agudas y retráctiles, pelaje espeso y suave, de diversos colores, y ojos cuya pupila se dilata para ver en la oscuridad.","plural":"gatos"},{"keyword":"gato","url":"https://static.arasaac.org/pictograms/9881/9881_500.png","descripcion":" m. y f. Mamífero carnívoro doméstico de cabeza redonda, lengua muy áspera, patas cortas armadas de uñas fuertes, agudas y retráctiles, pelaje espeso y suave, de diversos colores, y ojos cuya pupila se dilata para ver en la oscuridad.","plural":"gatos"},{"keyword":"gato","url":"https://static.arasaac.org/pictograms/9879/9879_500.png","descripcion":" m. y f. Mamífero carnívoro doméstico de cabeza redonda, lengua muy áspera, patas cortas armadas de uñas fuertes, agudas y retráctiles, pelaje espeso y suave, de diversos colores, y ojos cuya pupila se dilata para ver en la oscuridad.","plural":"gatos"}]
```

Comment: Lo que muestras es una cadena en formato [JSON](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). Si la misma la recibes en una variable, basta [convertirla en un Objeto de Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) (en este caso será un `Array`) y recorrer los elementos del mismo para obtener los valores de la propiedad `descripción` de cada elemento, de esta forma no necesitas ninguna expresión regular. En todo caso, ¿qué has intentado?. Te invito a leer [ask] y [mcve]. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Supongamos que ya tienes el objeto json en formato array y en la variable array.

```
const arrayTodasLasDescripciones = array.map(e => e.descripcion)
```